# How to communicate to database using AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am trying to communicate to database from JavaScript using AJAX.

I have followed one article [A beginner’s guide for consuming a WCF service in JavaScript using ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/wcfinjavascript.aspx) to understand about this functionality. I have done everything like exactly shown in the article. But, I couldn't understand how to set up the communication from JavaScript file.

Please note that as per my project requirement I can use only the second technique explained in the article: Using a Service Interface Defined in the Class Library.

Can anybody please suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps
1) Creat a WCF service in your application.
2) Then add reference to your WCF Service.
3) Then add wcf service to the script manager control of your page
4) Now you can access the wcf service on your page.

Step by Step tutorial using VB.NET
http://v4.ajaxtutorials.com/tutorials/javascript/expose-wcf-service-to-javascript-in-asp-net-4-0-vb/

Comment: yah but @Ashok kumar want use that in javascript

Comment: yes you can use the service in javascript, just use the name of service. For accessing in javascript I add the wcf service in the script manager control of the page. You can access all of the methods of wcf by their name.

Comment: What I'm saying, the same is done on this web page. http://v4.ajaxtutorials.com/tutorials/javascript/expose-wcf-service-to-javascript-in-asp-net-4-0-vb/

Comment: ya but i think @Ashok kumar not interested, because he did not answer or vote this solutions

Comment: To access the service, I have used the following technique:
var todo = new ServiceLibrary.TODO(); //InterfaceNamespacename.LINQTableName
Now, I got the solution.

My JavaScript code is like below:
function AddAToDo(txtNewTask) {
    var newTask = document.getElementById(txtNewTask).value;
    var todo = new ServiceLibrary.TODO(); //InterfaceNamespacename.LINQTableName
    todo.DESCRIPTION = newTask;
    todo.STATUS = "test";
    ServiceLibrary.IToDoService.AddToDo(todo, OnSuccess, OnFailure);
}...

Answer (score 0):

I used the following JavaScript code to get data from the database over AJAX:

```
$(function () {
    var search = $("#<%=txtAccountNo.ClientID%>");
    search.watermark('Enter Account No');
    search.autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/") %>AutoCompleteService.asmx/GetAccountNo',
            data: "{'prefixText':'" + search.val() + "','count':'10','contextKey':''}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d != null) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item
                        }
                    }))
                }
             },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error) {
                //alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
        },
     minLength: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: To access the Service: I have used the following technique: